# How to check that a user/password is expired in AIX?

Tags: password, aix

I can check that the user is expired or not with:

```
lsuser -f USERNAME | fgrep expires
```

But how can I check that the user's password is expired or not? Are there any other "expiring" things that can cause trouble? [so that user can't login, because he can only reach a server through FTP and his password expired, and he can't change it, because he hasn't got SSH access to give out the "passwd" command to update his password.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there any `chage` sort of command on AIX? check /etc/shadow file thats where the expiry information is stored.

Update: It seems there is a passwdexpired subroutine that can be loaded and Checks the user's password to determine if it has expired. However, it seems to be used as root.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.basetechref%2Fdoc%2Fbasetrf1%2Fpasswdexpired.htm

This link has excellent documentation of what you would require

http://www.torontoaix.com/scripting/when_pwd_exp

As demonstrated earlier in the above article, the expiry of a password is governed by the maxage attribute.

```
For example:
maxage=0 means never to expire
maxage=2 means will expire in two weeks.
```

AIX stores the time in the epoch format in seconds, so first you must determine how many seconds in a week, as this is how maxage measures the time between password expiry, that is in week numbers. There are 86400 seconds in a day, so multiplying that by seven comes in at 604800. So there are 604800 seconds in a week. The next command you need to look at is the pwdadm, which in turn queries the file /etc/security/passwd. This file holds the values in seconds when a user last changed their password. Interrogating the file or using the pwdadm command will return the same result. 
For this demonstration, let us query the user spoll:

```
# grep -p "spoll:" /etc/security/passwd
spoll:
        password = EvqNjMMwJzXnc
        lastupdate = 1274003127
        flags =       ADMCHG

# pwdadm -q spoll
spoll:
        lastupdate = 1274003127
        flags = ADMCHG
```

You can see the lastupdate value in seconds from the above output. In other words, the last time the password was changed:
1274003127

Next, using the lsuser or interrogating the file with /etc/security/user, you can determine the number of weeks before the user spoll password will expire:

```
# grep -p "spoll:" /etc/security/user
spoll:
        admin = false
        maxage = 4

# lsuser -a maxage spoll
spoll maxage=4
```

You can see from the above output that the number of weeks before password expiry is 4.
The next task is then to multiply the number of seconds in a week by the number of weeks before the user spoll password is due to expire. In this case, it is 4:
604800 * 4

```
# expr 604800 \* 4
2419200
```

Next, you need to add the maxage value in seconds (604800 * 4) to the last time the password was changed:
2419200 +   1274003127

```
# expr 2419200 + 1274003127
1276422327
```

You can now convert that number of seconds from UNIX epoch into a more meaningful current time presentation. You can use different tools, but for this demonstration you'll use gawk with the strftime function:

```
# gawk 'BEGIN {print strftime("%c",'1276422327')}'
Sun Jun 13 10:45:27 BST 2010
```

The above calculation gives the time of the next password expiry.
So, you now know that user spoll's password was last changed on ( from the pwdadm command):

```
# gawk 'BEGIN {print strftime("%c",'1274003127')}'
Sun May 16 10:45:27 BST 2010
```

And that it will expire on:

```
Sun Jun 13 10:45:27 BST 2010
```

------------------Perl script-let--------

```
#!/bin/perl
use POSIX qw(strftime);
$maxage=4; 
$last_update = 1274003127
$max_week_seconds = 86400 * $maxage;
print strftime("%C ", localtime($max_week_seconds));
```

---

Comment: Link is invalid: http://www.torontoaix.com/scripting/when_pwd_exp

Answer (score 0):

convertthis-to-normal-time(last-pwdupdate-time-in-seconds+maxage-in-seconds)

Comment: #!/bin/perl
use POSIX qw(strftime);
$maxage=4; 
$last_update = 1274003127
$max_week_seconds = 86400 * $maxage;
print strftime("%C ", localtime($max_week_seconds));

Answer (score 0):

You can find out through the System Management Interface Tool (`smit`). The console version is `smitty`

Comment: Answers generally require more explanation than a mere command name.  Please elaborate, or move this to a comment.

Comment: I would add to this answer, but I can't find the man page anywhere. Mentioning what flags to give it and what the output will look like would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I made this script to check hopefully this helps someone else out:

```
#!/bin/sh

###############################################################################
# Script Name: aix_chk_user_expires.sh
#
# Author: Chris Alderson
#
# Purpose: Check when a user expires in AIX
#
# NOTES: Please change the value of $oozer to the id you desire to check against
#
##############################################################################

# Set value to specify a user

oozer='<username>'

#get epoch time for the time since last updated
time_since_last_update_in_epoch=$(lssec -f /etc/security/passwd -s $oozer -a lastupdate | cut -d= -f2)
#get the max age number of weeks from luser
max_age=$(lsuser -f $oozer | grep maxage | cut -d= -f2)
#multiply maxage by 7 to get number of days password will last
max_age_in_days=$(echo $((( max_age * 7 ))))
# multiply number of days by how many seconds in a day to get total seconds until change
# We will use this later to add to $time_since_last_update_in_epoch
max_age_in_epoch=$(echo $((( $max_age_in_days * 86400 ))) )
# Create new variable to store the total of max age in seconds and epoch of updated password
time_until_expires_in_epoch=$(echo $((( $max_age_in_epoch + $time_since_last_update_in_epoch ))))

#take epoch times and pass them to perl to give them a readible format
time_last_updated=$(perl -le 'print scalar localtime $ARGV[0]' ${time_since_last_update_in_epoch})


if [[ $max_age -eq 0 ]]; then

    time_of_expiration=$(echo "non-expiring password")
else
    ##take epoch times and pass them to perl to give them a readible format
    time_of_expiration=$(perl -le 'print scalar localtime $ARGV[0]' ${time_until_expires_in_epoch})
fi



echo "${oozer}'s password last updated: $time_last_updated"
echo "${oozer}'s password will expire: $time_of_expiration"
```

Output looks like this:

```
user's password last updated: Mon Jul 31 17:00:13 2017
user's password will expire: Mon Oct 23 17:00:13 2017
```