# How to know when my password will expire?

Tags: password, aix

How can I get to know when my password will expire? I'm running IBM AIX.

Answer (score 4):

There is no dedicated command to check when your password will expire. You can check the password expiration policy for any user via [lsuser](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/lsuser.htm) as root with `lsuser -a maxage username` or with `pwdadm -q username` if any other flags are set for that user.

If you would like to know when your password expires, have a look at this question which is the same as yours: [How to check that a user/password is expired in AIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23923/how-to-check-that-a-user-password-is-expired-in-aix)

Some more information via

- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-password_expiry/
- http://www.torontoaix.com/scripting/passwd-expiry-scr

Answer (score 0):

Use `chage -l pooja`, where *pooja* is your login name.  This command is available also to the nonprivileged user.

If you're root, you can also use `passwd -S pooja`.

Edit: my mistake, these commands work on Linux but (as signaled by other readers) not on AIX.

Comment: Voted down because neither of the two commands will work on AIX. chage doesn't even exist, and the AIX [passwd command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds4/passwd.htm) only supports changing the GECOS field and the login shell.

Comment: Sorry, I must have missed out the AIX tag. I'll leave the answer as it can help other Linux users.